# Calculate $ a_n\:=\:n^3\left(\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}-\sqrt{2}n\right) $

Tags: limits

I struggle for a while solving limit of this chain:
$
 a_n\:=\:n^3\left(\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}-\sqrt{2}n\right)
$

I know from WolframAlpha result will be  $ \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}} $, but step-by-step solution is overcomplicated(28 steps). Usually I solve limits like this by property $ \left(a-b\right)\left(a+b\right)=a^2-b^2 $

I made this far: 
$$ 
\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(n^3\left(\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^{4\:}+1}}-\sqrt{2}n\right)\right)
=n^3\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}-n^4\sqrt{2}=\frac{\left(n^3\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}-n^4\sqrt{2}\right)\left(n^3\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}+n^4\sqrt{2}\right)}{\left(n^3\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}+n^4\sqrt{2}\right)} = \frac{-n^8+n^6\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^3\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}+n^4\sqrt{2}}$$

I will appreciate every help. Thank you

Comment: $\sqrt{1+x}=1+{x}/{2}...$

Comment: Does $n→∞$ or some other limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a_n=\frac{n^3(n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}-2n^2)}{\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}+\sqrt{2}n}$$
$$=\frac{n^3(\sqrt{n^4+1}-n^2)}{\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}+\sqrt{2}n}$$
$$=\frac{n^3}{(\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}+\sqrt{2}n)(\sqrt{n^4+1}+n^2)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^4}}}+\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^4}}+1)}$$
Now, apply $\lim_n\to \infty$ on both sides and get the result.

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

First, let $n=\frac 1x$ and compose Taylor series around $x=0$; back to $n$, get successively
$$\sqrt{n^4+1}=n^2+\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}=\sqrt{2} n+\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2} n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \begin{align}L&=\lim_\limits{n\to \infty }\left(n^3\left(\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^{4\:}+1}}-\sqrt{2}n\right)\right)\\&
=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}n^3\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}-n^4\sqrt{2}\\&=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(n^3\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}-n^4\sqrt{2}\right)\left(n^3\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}+n^4\sqrt{2}\right)}{\left(n^3\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}+n^4\sqrt{2}\right)}\\&=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{-n^8+n^6\sqrt{n^4+1}}{n^3\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}+n^4\sqrt{2}}\\&=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\dfrac{-n^5+n^3\sqrt{n^4+1}}{\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}+n\sqrt 2}\\&=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\dfrac{-n^5+n^3\cdot n^2\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{n^4}}}{n\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{n^4}}}+n\sqrt2}\\&=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n^5\left[\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{n^4}}-1\right]}{n\left[\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{n^4}}}+\sqrt2\right]}\\&\boxed{\text{Let }n=\dfrac1m,\text{ so as }n\to\infty,m\to 0}\\&=\lim_\limits{m\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+m^4}-1}{m^4\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+m^4}}+\sqrt2}\\&\boxed{\text{As }x\approx 0,(1+x)^n\approx 1+nx}\\&=\lim_\limits{m\to 0}\dfrac{1+\dfrac12m^4-1}{m^4\sqrt{1+1+\dfrac12m^4}+\sqrt 2}\\&=\lim_\limits{m\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac12}{\sqrt{2+\dfrac12m^4}+\sqrt2}\\&=\lim_\limits{m\to0}\dfrac1{2\sqrt2\sqrt{1+\dfrac14m^4}+2\sqrt2}\\&=\lim_\limits{m\to0}\dfrac1{2\sqrt2\left(1+\dfrac18m^4\right)+2\sqrt2}\\&=\boxed{\dfrac1{4\sqrt2}}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

From the numerator and denominator take $-n^{3}$ as common term and then rationalize the numerator again. 
Once you do that you will be left with :

$$\frac{n^{3}}{(n^{2}+\sqrt{n^{4}+1})(\sqrt{n^{2}+\sqrt{n^{4}+1}}+n\sqrt{2})}$$

Divide the numerator and denominator by $n^{3}$, and once you divide the denominator by $n^{3}$ for the first factor divide n^{2} and the second factor just n. You will get :
$$\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{(1/n^{4})+1})(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{(1/n^{4})+1}}+\sqrt{2})}$$

Apply the limit you will get the answer as $\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}$

Answer (score 2):

You may proceed as follows transforming the limit into a derivative of a function at $0$.

First set $n = \frac{1}{t}$ and consider $t \to 0^+$:

\begin{eqnarray*}  n^3\left(\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}-\sqrt{2}n\right)
  & \stackrel{n=\frac{1}{t}}{=}  &   \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^4}+1}}-\sqrt{2}\frac{1}{t}}{t^3}\\
  & =  &   \frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+t^4}}-\sqrt{2}}{t^4}\\
  & \stackrel{y=t^4}{=}  &   \frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+y}}-\sqrt{2}}{y}\\
  & \stackrel{y\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow}  &   f'(0) = \left.\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+y}}\cdot \sqrt{1+y}} \right|_{y=0} = \boxed{\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}}\mbox{ for } f(y) =\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+y}}\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Like [Calculate $ a_n\:=\:n^3\left(\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^4+1}}-\sqrt{2}n\right) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080173/calculate-a-n-n3-left-sqrtn2-sqrtn41-sqrt2n-right/3080235#3080235),

$$F=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(n^3\left(\sqrt{n^2+\sqrt{n^{4}+1}}-\sqrt{2}n\right)\right)
=\lim_{y\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+y}}-\sqrt2}y$$

Set $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+y}}-\sqrt2=u\implies u\to0$

and $1+\sqrt{1+y}=(u+\sqrt2)^2=2+2\sqrt2u+u^2$

$\implies y=(1+2\sqrt2u+u^2)^2-1=4\sqrt2u+O(u^2)$

$$F=\lim_{u\to0^+}\dfrac u{4\sqrt2u+O(u^2)}=?$$